# Send inovice via email using template

Tags: xero-api

I try to send a specific invoice via Email, using the provided endpoint. However, this endpoint doesn't allow me to set email template, attachPDF, etc. Is there anyway that I can achieve it via API? Thanks for your help in advance.

POST https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/aa682059-c8ec-44b9-bc7f-344c94e1ffae/Email

I expect to have the following as payload.

```
{
  "attachPDF": true,
  "includeFiles": false,
  "message": "message",
  "selectedTemplateID": "c650159c-aa16-44a8-a17f-74f9ec3da916",
  "sendMeACopy": false,
  "subject": "Invoice INV-0047",
  "to": [{ "address": "email@demo.com", "name": "DEMO" }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to choose a template or send pdf attachments through the API.